# FullCalendar "Calendar" Month View Starting from Current Day

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a need to use the FullCalendar plugin's month view, but with a small twist... I need the month view to be a calendar month (4 weeks) from the currently selected date, not a month proper (Jan, Feb, etc). In other words, I need the top left column to be the currently selected date, with the calendar rendering 4 weeks after that in month view.

Something similar to what is provided by thefirstDay property in agendaWeek view is close to what I am after. firstDay only sets the day of the week though, not a specific date within the month as the first day.

Comment: Like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119213/fullcalendar-first-row-month-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to show a Thursday in the upper left hand corner then what you've got isn't a calendar. It's  a table data.

FullCalendar's `firstDay` is just for switching between starting on a Monday (European style) and starting on a Sunday (US style).

Comment: "If you're going to show a Thursday in the upper left hand corner then what you've got isn't a calendar." Please define 'calendar'.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
firstDay: new Date().getDay()
```

in the parameters.

Comment: Anyone wanting to comment their -1?

Comment: i guess this will not work if you navigate through calendar right ?